ClerkClient.emailAddresses.createEmailAddress does not send verification email
So im trying to build a custom settings page for my SaaS which uses Clerk. I am able to create a new email for the user, but i am setting "verified" to false, since i want the user to receive an email to verify, but clerk does not send any email?
const emailAddress = await ClerkClient.emailAddresses.createEmailAddress({
    userId: user.id,
    emailAddress: email,
    primary: false,
    verified: false,
});

If i use the regular built in clerk component  and try adding an email, it send a verification email.
Does anyone have the same issue?
I have tried scanning the docs but there is very little about this, and the little info there is does not seem to be correct.
